# Ruby on Rails - column name is the same that relationship name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working with a legacy database and I cannot change it.

```
user
---------
user_id | name | plan
1         'bob'   20
```

`plan` is a foreign key to plan table.
So in RoR, if I write `User.find(1).plan` I get 20 but I want to get the plan object

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan, :foreign_key => :plan # this causes conflict because the names should not be equal
```

Can I change the name of accessor column in Rail?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

> :class_name is what you are looking for.

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha, :class_name => 'Plan', :foreign_key => 'plan'
end
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying get a Plan object when I write `user.plan`